# Need to Check if the date is greater that 15 days

Tags: jquery, date

Sorry if this is a duplicated question, can't able to get any solution in web so far

Problem

I need to calculate if a date is greater that 15 days in jquery

My code

```
var date = $("#invDate").val();
            var d = new Date(date.split("/").reverse().join("-"));
            var dd = d.getDate();
            var mm = d.getMonth() + 1;
            var yy = d.getFullYear();
            var correctDate = dd + "/" + mm + "/" + yy;
            var newdate = new Date(correctDate); 
 var limiteDays = newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + 15);
if (newdate > limiteDays) {
                   alert("greater");
               }
               else {
                   alert("lesser")
               }
```

could any body please correct me if am wrong

Comment: I love how he apologises for if it is a duplicated question and it got duplicated instantly

Comment: @Rory McCrossan the duplicated question is to calculate days between two dates but my question is different please read the question

Comment: Your question is *exactly* the same. You just take the result of the calculation and check if it's more than `15`

Comment: I don't want to calculate days I need to check the date is greater than 15 days suppose if my date is 01/10/2016 okay but if it is 16/10/2016 means I need to get a message

Comment: ... which is exactly what the duplicate will do

Comment: still I could not able to get it